# How to interchange x and y axis in pyqtgraph PlotWidget

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqtgraph

Is it possible to interchange `x-axis` to `y-axis` in `PlotWidget` in `pyqtgraph`. As these widgets are derived from `QGraphicsWidgetItem`, I used `setTransform()` method, but it rotate all the texts as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just use something like `plot(y, x)` instead of `plot(x, y)`?

Comment: Yes, but I want to keep the original interface as I have very complex sets of data to plot.

Comment: Still facing this issue did you come across a good solution?